# Using JSON to populate ComboBox. Dojo 1.7 breaks it. :-(

Tags: json, combobox, dojo

I have an app  that was populating a combobox with a JSON source. The HTML is below......

```
<label for="user">User: </label>
<input dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox" class="selectionNav tableData" value="" name="user" id="sample/user">
```

The JSON from sample/user" is here......

```
{
"identifier": "user",
"label": "label",
"items": [
    {
        "user": null,
        "label": null
    },
    {
        "user": "Joe Wilkie",
        "label": "Joe Wilkie"
    }
  ]
}
```

Previous to dojo 1.7 this worked like a champ! After upgrading the dojo, I noticed in firebug that the JSON is still being fetched ok and is valid but it's no longer populating the comboBox.

Any idea from anyone how this can be fixed? Many thanks in advance.
Janie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default search attribute on the ComboBox is name, which isn't in the store.  Add the `searchAttr` to the combo box.

```
<input dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox" searchAttr="label" ...
```

Here is my full test code that worked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dojo/1.7.2/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
    <style type="text/css">html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }</style>
    <script src="dojo/1.7.2/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
    <script>require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore", "dijit/form/ComboBox"], 

    function(ready, Store, ComboBox) {
      ready(function() {
        var store = new Store({data: {
          "identifier": "user",
          "label": "label",
          "items": [
              {
                  "user": null,
                  "label": null
              },
              {
                  "user": "Joe Wilkie",
                  "label": "Joe Wilkie"
              }
            ]
        }});

    dijit.byId('user').set('store', store);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <label for="user">User: </label>
    <input dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox" searchAttr="label" class="selectionNav tableData" value="" name="user" id="user" />        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Craig, I deconstructed your example and put together a solution. You get the answer karma for preserving the <input> element. (I have an onChange event firing on it). I only needed to add a <div> above the <input> to specify the url,.... like this

<div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" jsId="userStore" url="sample/user">
</div>

1.7 apparently heralded in some major changes and without your help I probably would've been here a while.